# Blender Edge Flow/UV Mapping help needed

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, workflow, edges

I started a project recently with a sewer scene, and I'm trying to make a circular hole in the cylinder I'm using for the wall to make a ladder that leads into the sewer. However, when cutting the hole, I've been able to get some decent edge flow, but I can't seem to avoid UV stretching. Also, I'm using Adaptive Subdivision to raise the bricks, and for some reason it doesn't seem to be working all of the sudden (before I cut the hole, and sometimes when I was reworking the mesh it would work). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
[image: heres the topology]
[image: here is the stretching]
[image: the untextured model]
Here's the file (copy and paste the link into a web browser, the file was too large for blendexchange so I used my google drive):
drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1W0Y0agLwyviXrVUeinJHthQMm4NyExjv

Comment: You should display some screenshots here to make your problem more understandable. Also, you didn't pack any image so we can only see a pink texture, please pack everything (File > External Data > Pack All Into .Blend) and reload your file.

Comment: thanks @moonboots I updated the post so it should more clear, the textures are now packed in and I added some screenshots :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Adaptive Subdivision, maybe create a new question for this. About your first question: Your stretched texture is created by the ngons, You need to use quads instead, so just correct this and it should work.

[image]